# Different seed for each Migration

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

Is it possible to have distinct seed data for each migration?

Database data could have been changed since first migration has been run. So it must not be used in future migrations. But i still want it when first migration is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new empty migration using the following command in package manager console:

```
Add-Migration DefaultAddressData
```

After this create sql script for up and down method that generates and reverts the seed data

```
namespace Northwind.CodeFirst.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class DefaultAddressData : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            this.Sql(@"INSERT INTO dbo.Addresses(Name, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, State)
                       VALUES ('John', 'House address 1', 'street address 1', 'city 1', 'some state'),
                              ('Name 2', 'House address 2', 'street address 2', 'city 2', 'some state');
                      INSERT INTO dbo.Addresses(Name, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, State)
                       VALUES ('Name 3', 'House address 3', 'street address 1', 'city 2', 'some state');");

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            this.Sql(@"DELETE FROM dbo.Addresses
                       WHERE NAME IN('John', 'Name 2', 'Name 3');");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx, this can do what i want.

Answer (score 0):

The DbMigrationsConfiguration Seed method will run after each migration is applied or every time its used if AutomaticMigrationsEnabled=true

Comment: I want to detect which migration is run. Some seed are not valid vor certain migrations.

Comment: By default all migrations are run up to the latest so you only need apply seed relevant for most recent migration.

Comment: That is what i do now but now i cannot go back when using a targetmigration which is older. then i must uncomment de seeding code.